# Interpreting dummy variable in semi-log model

Tags: categorical-data, log-linear

There are numerous theories on how to interpret the coefficients of dummy variables in a semi-log model but I still am not sure about it. 
Do we multiply the coefficient by 100 to get the change like any other continuous variables like age or do we log the values? 
One of the ways is to take the exponential of both sides of equation, then evaluate Y when D = 0 and when D = 1. The difference between these two values, divided by the expression for Y based on the starting value of D gives you the correct interpretation immediately. This sounds about right but we dont actually get a value for the Y variable so I am a bit confused here.

Thank you